# Ошибка запуска приложений MS Office

Tags: office

Установлен Office 2016. запуск любого приложения из него оканчивается выводом окна:[image: с сообщением]

Что это? Ошибка не гуглиться. Переустанавливал несколько раз. Что можно сделать?

Уточнения:
1. "Windows 10 Корпоративная 2015 с долгосрочным обслуживанием"
2. Office 2016 до этого был уже установлен и прекрасно работал. затем был штатно удален. 
3. Текущая установка из того же дистрибутива.

Comment: WIndows какой версии?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился шагами:

1. полное удаление всех приложений v.2016. Включая отдельно поставленные визио и прожект
2. далее, удаление папки root\Office16
3. новая установка после этого заработала